# error with fab button design with vector assets

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button, android-vectordrawable

I have used the dependencies to be used as suggested. below is the pic.
[build_gradle(module)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrqQj.png)

now I have selected a black plus icon from vector assets and named it as fab_plus, now I have this file in my drawable folder.
 fab_plus_XML
now I tried to used that fab_plus_XML like this. Pic below.
[activity_main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfFXk.png)

Now my question is why is the fab_plus is showing in red.

thanks in advance. pls, help me, someone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post screenshots of your code but [edit] your question and paste its relevant parts into. Also check [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things wrong with the way you are specifying the drawable. To refer to a drawable within your project, you simply use `@drawable/your_drawable` and to allow backward compatibility of VectorDrawables you should use `app:srcCompat` as [per the guidance.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution)

So in your ImageView, instead of

```
android:src="@android:drawable/fab_plus"
```

you should have

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab_plus"
```

You will also need to make sure the `app` namespace is included at the top of your layout `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` along with the current `android` and `tools` namespaces.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked for me. Your explanation is very clear and easily understandable. Thanks again. :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to use:

```
 app:srcCompat
```

instead of

```
 android:src
```

but the tooltip there should exactly tell you this and AFAIR even offer a quick-fix